# How to write a command that uses sends the output of an arbitrary git command to fzf?

Tags: git, fzf

I've been messing around a bit with `fzf` and I'd like to be able to run a command that does something like take the output of `diff -w -M origin/main...HEAD --name-only` and make the contents available in a preview window.

I've gotten this far, with some copy/paste from the docs:

```
command! -bang -nargs=* Gdomo
   \ call fzf#vim#grep(
   \   'git diff -w -M origin/main...HEAD --name-only', 0,
   \   fzf#vim#with_preview({'dir': systemlist('git rev-parse --show-toplevel')[0]}), <bang>0))
```

That gets me the preview window, but selecting any of the files results in:

```
Error detected while processing function 24[30]..<SNR>53_callback[23]..function 24[30]..<SNR>53_callback:
line   21:
Vim(let):E684: list index out of range: 1
```

I'm guessing that trying to wrap `grep` is my first mistake, but I've looked at the plugin code and it's not clear to me what a better approach would be.

Comment: Aren't you simply looking for [`:h :GFiles`](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim/blob/ee91c93d4cbc6f29cf82877ca39f3ce23d5c5b7b/doc/fzf-vim.txt#L120) which is built-in in fzf.vim and which opens the not staged files? And if `:GFiles` is not exactly what you're looking for you can either give it more arguments or look at [fzf#vim#gitfiles](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim/blob/ee91c93d4cbc6f29cf82877ca39f3ce23d5c5b7b/autoload/fzf/vim.vim#L626) code which should give your enough inspiration to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks. `:GFiles` is not quite what I'm looking for. I want a preview window with just the files in a branch which have diverged from `main`, even if there are no unstaged changes. This helps me quickly find, for example, a unit test which I want to tweak or just continue to work on files that I care about which are not currently open in a buffer. I'll have a closer look at `fzf#vim#gitfiles`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I was overthinking this and I also missed some of the documentation. `fzf#run` can accept an arbitrary command which returns a list of files.

A working example without a preview window:

```
command! GDomo
  \ call fzf#run({'source': 'git diff -w -M origin/main...HEAD --name-only', 'sink': 'e'})
```

A working example with a preview window:

```
command! GDomo
  \ call fzf#run(
  \   fzf#vim#with_preview(
  \     fzf#wrap({ 'source': 'git diff -w -M origin/main...HEAD --name-only' })
  \   )
  \ )
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @oalders.

I created an unrestricted find files command using `fd`, please checkout this issue: https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim/issues/1454

Here's the source code:

```
    command! -bang -nargs=? -complete=dir UnrestrictedFiles
        \ call fzf#run(
        \   fzf#vim#with_preview(
        \     fzf#wrap({ 'source': 'fd -tf -tl -i -u --exclude ".git" '.shellescape(<q-args>) }, <bang>0)
        \   )
        \ )
```